# How can I configure the Microsoft-Hosted Agent to be interactive?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I am configuring my yaml file run coded UI and Web Tests and I would like to use Microsoft-Hosted agent for that. Is that a way to configure the agent to be interactive via my yaml file?

I have configured successfully my self hosted agent to be interactive, my I would like to migrate the pipeline to the microsoft infrastructure

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Berton ,I am following up to confirm if you have time to check my post. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kim Xu MSFT. Sorry for not answer before, yes it clarified my doubt. In fact, since the MS Hosted Agent does not support interactive mode, I will continue using the self hosted approach. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Berton , glad that it is clearly clarified. If the answer helps, you may consider this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not configure the MS-hosted agent to be interactive, this is not supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#microsoft-hosted-agents

> I have configured successfully my self hosted agent to be interactive

For your scenario, self-hosted agent is suggested: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service

[image]